# Global beforeEach/afterEach for ember qunit tests

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, qunit, ember-qunit, ember-testing

My app stores some information about the current session in `localStorage`. Therefore I need my tests to clear `localStorage` before or after each single test throughout all test files. Is there a way to define a `beforeEach` or `afterEach` callback globally instead of on each test file?

Answer (score 2):

We had wrapped ember-qunit's `module`, `moduleFor` and `moduleForComponent` for a nearly the same reason. And we are importing those wrappers instead of ember-qunit.

Another suggestion is to wrap localStorage with a service. Never access to localStorage except this service. So you can use a mock implementation of it in tests.

**Updated:**

How it is realised:

```
import { moduleFor, moduleForModel, test, only, setResolver }    from 'ember-qunit';
import { moduleForComponent as qunitModuleForComponent } from 'ember-qunit';

function moduleForComponent(name, description, callbacks) {
   //our implementation that wraps "qunitModuleForComponent" 
   //eg. init commonly used services vs.
}

export {
  moduleFor,
  moduleForComponent,
  moduleForModel,
  test,
  only,
  setResolver
};
```

Pros:

- Prevents code duplication
- Centralize unit test management
- Easy to add new methods for custom needs, such as: `moduleForValidatableComponent`, `moduleForLocalStorage`

Cons:

- *ember-cli* generates tests those are importing `ember-qunit`. Developers must change the import statements to these wrappers. It was sometimes forgotten. (When a test fails, developers remember that they need to change import statements.)
- For some tests, wrapping is unnecessary.

Comment: Thanks for the tip about wrapping localStorage with a service. But I still prefer what you mention about wrapping those ember-qunit's methods, given that this feature could become handy beyond my current specific need for it. Could you elaborate on how that wrapping works?